# How export all firestore data to excel of csv?

Tags: firebase, csv, google-cloud-firestore, export-to-csv

In my database has one users table in that table have many documents(users) in each documents have many subcollections. I want export all users table with all subcollections to excel or csv. Is it possible ? Can export all data ?

**database users collection**
[image]

**image of one of the subcollection**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[firefoo](https://firefoo.app/) is the fastest and very comfortable tools to Import your CSV/json to Firestore and export firestore to csv/json.

https://firefoo.app/docs/firestore-export-import/export-csv

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to provide a more direct way to do this without any external tools.

You can export the collection you want to use as a CSV.

From Firestore click "More in google cloud" and do import/export.

Once the export is placed in a Cloud Storage bucket. You can use BigQuery to get the CSV.

1. Create a Dataset
2. Create a table and in the new table creation, you can select the Firestore export file from Cloud Storage
3. Query the entire new table
4. Click "Save Results" > "CSV"

Comment: Hi @Matthew, How do I "Query the entire new table"?